# Navigating between multiple Tabulator tables

Tags: tabulator

I'd like to know how to programmatically navigate to a specific cell on a Tabulator table.  I see the documentation only specifies how to navigate up/down/left/right/prev/next, but it doesn't give the option to navigate to a specific cell.

I ask because I'm implementing multiple Tabulator table instances on my page, and there are certain cells that I'd like to take the user to another cell located in a different table when they tab out of it.  I'm I have all the table instances saved neatly in an object, so I can leverage any available functions when needed.

There just doesn't seem to be a function for navigating to a specific cell, is there?

I've tried calling the focus() event on a specific cell instance, but that doesn't navigate the user to it.  By navigate, I mean simulate as if the user clicked on the cell to edit it.

Comment: Try calling `edit()` on the specific cell.